# tensorflow lite conversion for LSTM Model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, toco

I am trying to covert a tensorflow (LSTM) based model to tensorflow lite using tensorflow TOCO and `tf_convert` tool, but the tensorflow lite model after conversion is around 245MB where as the original tensorflow mobile is around ~1MB.

Below is the command I have used

```
bazel run --config=opt //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco -- \  
    --input_file= <inputfile> \
    --output_file= <outputfile> \
    --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
    --output_format=TFLITE \
    --input_shape=1,1\
    --input_array=input\
    --output_array=output\
    --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
    --inference_type=FLOAT \
    --input_data_type=FLOAT \
    --allow_custom_ops
```

I have tried with the `--allow_custom_ops` and the size of the converted model is same with/without the custom operation in TOCO tool.

> 2018-08-27 18:09:18.538279: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before Removing unused ops: 4210 operators, 6021 arrays (0 quantized)
>   2018-08-27 18:09:19.255416: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before general graph transformations: 4210 operators, 6021 arrays (0
>   quantized) 2018-08-27 18:09:20.504422: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   After general graph transformations pass 1: 3604 operators, 6008
>   arrays (0 quantized) 2018-08-27 18:09:21.335526: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before dequantization graph transformations: 3604 operators, 6008
>   arrays (0 quantized) 2018-08-27 18:09:21.897161: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/allocate_transient_arrays.cc:329] Total
>   transient array allocated size: 15616 bytes, theoretical optimal
>   value: 15616 bytes.

Is there any plan for tensorflow to support the LSTM related operations in near future?

Comment: The same issue is registered in tensorflow GitHub https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17540